# Объект класса С++. Класс памяти extern. Внешний объект класса

Tags: c++, память

Как правильно объявлять, создавать и подключать extern объекты классов.

Например у меня есть класс ManagerKeyboard с расположением "Managers/ManagerKeyboard.h"

Как я понял:

```
**Modules_objects.h**
#pragma once
#include "Managers/ManagerKeyboard.h"
//Объявляем класс так..
extern class ManagerKeyboard;

**Modules_objects.cpp**
#include "Modules_objects.h"

//тут нужно создать (определить) этот объект

**Core.cpp**
#include "Modules_objects.h"
//тут обращаться к созданному объекту
```

Где объявлять этот объект если к примеру я буду обращаться к нему из разных частей программы?

Comment: Спецификатор `extern` применяется для объявления объектов класса (то бишь глобальных переменных). Код `extern class ManagerKeyboard;` не валиден. Собственно в С++ отсутствуют ситуации, в которых было бы необходимо использовать спецификатор `extern`. Единственное его применение - при объявлении объектов и функций с линковкой С (`extern "C" { … }`).

Comment: Правильнее было бы не иметь таких объектов, а пользоваться, например, шаблоном *одиночка* (aka *singleton*).

Comment: @VTT: "Отсутствуют ситуации"? Так а как же упомянутые вами же глобальные переменные?

Comment: @AnT Да, но нет ситуаций, когда было бы необходимо объявлять такие объекты и использовать `extern`. То бишь никаких глобальных переменных или констант с `extern` быть не должно (хотя ничто не мешает плодить из без всякой меры).

Comment: @VTT: Не своем понимаю. Вы имеете в виду чисто стилистические моменты?

Comment: @AnT Видимо да. [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil/148188#148188)

Comment: @AnT Ну почему чисто стилистические? Просто вместо глобальных "extern" объектов стоит использовать более толковые альтернативы.

Comment: @VTT А можно поподробнее про 'более толковые альтернативы'?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну вот хотя бы тот же многострадальный синглетон. Или (при экспорте из библиотеки) функция для доступа к этому объекту вместо экспорта переменной. Или рефакторинг глобальный переменной с неограниченным доступом в статическую переменную класса с ограниченным доступом.

Comment: @VTT Ладно, а чем они (не считая статической переменной класса) лучше просто глобальной переменной?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Глобальные константы не являются частью state, поэтому к ним это не относится. Я не вижу никаких осмысленных причин отказываться   глобальных констант.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Синглетон позволяет контролировать создание и время жизни глобального объекта. Предоставление  функции для доступа к переменной вместо самой переменной делает код гибче, так как отпадает привязка кода к существованию конкретной переменной (сегодня она сама по себе отдельная, а завтра станет полем объекта какого-то другого класса, или будет доставаться откуда-то или мокаться). В этом плане профит от наличия функции вместо доступа к самой переменной в целом аналогичен профиту от геттеров / сеттеров при доступе к полям класса.

Comment: @AnT С этим согласен.

Comment: @VTT Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @VTT Получается это аналогично тому если бы я создавал пустой указатель в классе и в этот класс через конструктор передавал бы указатель на объект за пределами видимости... А с синглтоном получается я создаю как бы объект второй но вместо создания получаю на указатель на первый объект и работаю далее. Да сейчас смотрю что это гибче... но по сути гибче на отсутствие двух файлов.. При синглтоне тоже больше кода появится в виде указателей и самого синглтона.. А еще инклудить для него файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В заголовочном файле пишете:

```
// "Modules_objects.h"

extern ManagerKeyboard my_object;
```

В одном любом `.cpp` файле пишете:

```
// Пусть будет "Modules_objects.cpp"

ManagerKeyboard my_object; // Тут можно указывать аргументы конструктора.
```

---

Если не хочется создавать отдельный `.cpp` файл, то есть альтернативный вариант.

В заголовочном файле пишете:

```
// "Modules_objects.h"

// Требует С++17
inline ManagerKeyboard my_object; // Тут можно указывать аргументы конструктора.
```

Comment: Но этот объект не видно в других классах

Comment: @Anton Почему это? Видно.

Comment: @Anton Его должно быть видно во всех файлах, инклюдящих `Modules_objects.h`. Но лучше так не делать...

Comment: Извиняюсь, по запаре забыл что у меня не указатель уже, а объект ))

Comment: А время жизни у него до закрытия программы? утечки не будет?

Comment: И почему предпочтительнее шаблон синглтон? почему extern это плохо?

Comment: @Anton Да, до закрытия. Нет, не будет. Речь не о том, что синглтон лучше, а о том, что (как некоторые считают) глобальные переменные (и синглтоны, по сути, тоже) - это в принципе плохо. [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil/148188#148188)

Comment: @Anton `extern` - это не плохо, плохо иметь глобальные переменные, а без них отпадает необходимость в использовании этого спецификатора.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Уровень конформизма в том вопросе просто зашкаливает...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Прочел тот пост о Зле глобальных переменных и не придумал варианта когда мой глобальный объект принесет это зло, он наоборот говорит о том что иногда эти глобальные обьекты нужны.. но так и не написал чем синглтон лучше кроме как возможностью ПЕРЕСОЗДАТЬ в процессе работы.. по указателю.